# getting warning from py2neo as Reconnecting (peer closed connection)

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

while creating nodes in neo4j using py2neo i am getting a warning as

**WARNING:py2neo.packages.httpstream.http:<~> Reconnecting (peer closed connection)**

is there any solution for this warning...sometimes i am getting an error as socket error also

Comment: I get the same error. Its very frequent. Would like some help with this issue..

Comment: you can use neo4jrest client (python module which is almost similar to py2neo)

Answer (score 0):

This message has a severity higher than it should; as far as I can tell, it's just a normal part of the way things work and can be ignored.

The author of py2neo and httpstream downgraded the message severity from *WARN* to *DEBUG* several years ago: https://github.com/nigelsmall/httpstream/commit/2a949791 although he has since increased the severity to *INFO*.